# Solr terms component complete field match

Tags: solr

i am new to Solr.
I am working with the terms component to get the Top Terms from a Field.
For Example:
I got the field "Firm" and there are many types of firms in it with the endings "gmbh" and "ag".
But i need this Field sepperated by the full content of it.
For Example: Mustermann gmbh, max gmbh, etc .....
I've tried many different fieldtypes in the schema.xml but nothing worked.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Lorenzo :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Facets in your request to get the "Top X of field Y"

E.g.

```
q=*&facet=true&facet.field=Firm&facet.limit=50&facet.minCount=1
```

When you use facet.limit you get the top X results. 
Your field Firm in the schema.xml should not use a Tokenizer, because you would get "mustermann" and "gmbh" instead of "mustermann gmbh" (I think "string" is in standard a field without a Tokenizer)

Don't forget to reindex if you have to change field values.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply.

Comment: Now the next Problem comes with it. If i use String as Fieldtype i get no results on my queries like Firm:Mustermann GmbH. I only get results on my queries if the fieldcontent is only one word.

Comment: Did you try to surround your queries with * (wildcard)? Like q=* AND Firm:Mustermann*. Your query needs the exact phrase or wildcard to deliver results.